# A classifier trained using the technique of word embedding(doc2vec) and logisitic regression misclassify the data

Tags: logistic-regression, word-embedding, doc2vec

I have a text classification problem in which the data set consist of 16 million records. The data is highly imbalanced and consist of almost 500 classes. I took the approach for word embedding and then used Logistic Regression to build a model in which the input is doc2vec matrix, the accuracy that i achieved was 88% but and recall score and F1-score is closet to 84% but when working on testing data the classifier doesn't perform well for example,
    if a text details are like i love traveling it is classified under Travel Tag, but if it encounters the text again the model classify it into some different category like unknown. This an unusual behavior that i have encountered in the model.

Code:

```
Y = " Love travelling"
tokens = cleanText(Y)
vector = model.infer_vector(tokens.split())
predict = logreg.predict(vector.reshape(1,-1))
print(predict)
```

Output Expected:
            **Travel**

Actual Output:
            **Unmapped**

Regressor code:

class_weight = class_weight.compute_class_weight('balanced', np.unique(y_train), y_train)

logreg = LogisticRegression(multi_class='multinomial', solver='lbfgs', class_weight="balanced")

logreg.fit(train_vectors_dbow, y_train)

Expected result:

```
   Text                 Label
1. I like to travel     Travel
2. I love to travel     Travel
```

Actual

```
   Text                 Label
1. I like to travel     Travel
2. I love to travel     Unmapped
```

Comment: "Doc2Vec" is related to, but not the same as, word-embedding algorithms, so it's not clear what you mean by "a model in which the input is doc2vec matrix". You should show some of your code, with indications of the text-prprocessing steps and algorithm parameters you've chosen. Poor performance on held-back testing data might be an indication your models have "overfit" on the training data, or that you're not prepping/providing the test cases in the same way as the training data, or other problems.

Comment: It'd be very odd for the same models to return different classifications for the exact same text, as you describe in your text. But, your examples show a different answer for slightly-different text, which would be more understandable. You should clarify those descriptions/examples to be more consistent and detailed about what you're seeing, including more detail about the balance/preponderance of labels in your training and test sets, and more detail about what typical texts look like.

Comment: @gojomo I am using doc2vec approach to create a doc2vec model and then use this per-trained as an input to my Logistic regression model and according to this train my model to predict the label. On any new data i use infer vector to generate the vector for the given text and then use that vector output to predict the label i have mentioned that code above.

Comment: Getting any single item wrong isn't very meaningful, since none of these techniques are perfect. It's only whether they do OK overall, or better than other techniques, that matters. (And, `Doc2Vec` works best with texts of dozens to hundreds of words, rather than just a few.) How were the models trained – with how much of what kind of data, and with what parameters? Is "Unmapped" an actual training label in your data? (What kind of multiclass logistic classifier are you using, and can you have it output its ranked, scored best guesses?)

Comment: So, i create a two vectors one for training and other for testing using the doc2vec approach where i give dm =0 once the doc2vec is trained i used the training vectors as an input to Logistic regression explaining the for the regressor above.train_vectors_dbow = get_vectors(model_dbow, len(X_train), 300, 'Train')

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your last comment at all. It'd be better to expand your question with more details, and more code, to clarify the answers to the questions I've asked. And, to be sure you're not using mysterious variables/functions whose value/code isn't shown. (As in your current text, `get_vectors()` or `class_weight` or `compute_class_weight()`.) Also, if you were consistent in which examples were succeeding/failing - is it `" Love travelling".split()` that's a problem, or `"I love to travel"` (via some unshown tokenization)? Or both?

Comment: So basically Both the examples are giving me errors when I test it I have these sentences repeating many times in a column and every time I am getting a different label which is not expected, it should always categorise sentence with similar context into the same label travel.

Comment: Without the extra details I've suggested adding to your question, it's hard to guess what's going wrong for you, and whether it's a serious problem or just a problem with a few difficult data items.

Comment: Also note that `infer_vector()` won't give the exact same vector for the same text on repeated runs – see <https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/wiki/recipes-&-faq#q12-ive-used-doc2vec-infer_vector-on-a-single-text-but-the-resulting-vector-is-different-each-time-is-there-a-bug-or-have-i-made-a-mistake-doc2vec-inference-non-determinism> – but if the models are strong & adequate `infer_vector()` parameters used, the 'jitter' from that behavior shouldn't affect downstream classification that much.

Comment: While going through the link you stated above i have two question related to this one where they state a model can be underpowered/overfit for this i use the cross validation check and the accuracy resulted is approx 85% and second the large values of epoch is that should be used while training the doc2vec or at the time of infer_vector we should specify the epoch.

Comment: True cross-validation should help serve as a check against overfitting, but without seeing more details of your code & parameter choices, that or other things could still be an issue. You can set `epochs` both when the model is initially created, whenever calling `train()`, and when calling `infer_vector()`.